# Why are iostream sentry objects called "cerberos" in the standard?

Tags: c++, iostream, naming, naming-conventions

I was wondering what `__cerb` means in the `libstdc++` of `g++`, and I found out that this seems to be a short name for `cerberos` as named in the official C++ standard document.

**§ 22.3.1 / 3:**

> [ Example: An iostream `operator<<` might be implemented as:
>
> ```
> template <class charT, class traits>
> basic_ostream<charT,traits>&
> operator<< (basic_ostream<charT,traits>& s, Date d) {
>                                                             //      !!!!!!!!!!
>   typename basic_ostream<charT,traits>::sentry cerberos(s); // <--- !! HERE !!
>                                                             //      !!!!!!!!!!
>   if (cerberos) {
>     ios_base::iostate err = ios_base::iostate::goodbit;
>     tm tmbuf; d.extract(tmbuf);
>     use_facet<time_put<charT,ostreambuf_iterator<charT,traits> > >(
>       s.getloc()).put(s, s, s.fill(), err, &tmbuf, ’x’);
>     s.setstate(err);            // might throw
>   }
>   return s;
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Why are iostream `sentry` objects called `cerberos`, and what does `cerberos` actually mean?

Comment: So just a generic name for a guard? And why cerber **o** s?

Comment: The person who used that name must be immensely happy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Cerberus was the three headed dog<sup>1</sup> who guarded the gates of hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerberus), keeping those trapped within from crossing back over the river Styx. Whomever wrote that section fancied Greek and/or Roman mythology and decided it would be an applicable name for a local variable sentry.

As to why it ends in *os*, one can imagine three scenarios:

1. They completely forgot the rules for Greek and Latin noun declinations and thought that was how it is spelled
2. I completely forgot the rules for Greek and Latin noun declinations and am pointing out a non-issue.
3. They conflated the spellings of Cerberus and Kerberos, giving birth to Cerberos the basic_stream sentry of Greek and Roman descent.

<sub>1. Apparently the number of heads on Cerberus is variable. Perhaps this is better expressed as the *"N-headed dog, where N is greater than or equal to 1."*</sub>

Comment: Or possibly 3. They mixed up the Latin and Greek names, *Kerberos* and *Cerberus*.

Comment: Or 4, the os is a reference to the fact they are writing ostream.